# I want to accurately align the boundaries of a map in QGIS

Tags: gis, qgis, geotiff

I have placed a tiff file on a Google map in QGIS.
Looking at the captured QGIS image, the two maps only overlap by half.

[image: Captured QGIS image]

**QGIS version : 3.34.5-Prizren**

tiff file : AgResStock_test.tif (download   http://gofile.me/79lJx/UWaIkkuyh)

```
# gdalinfo AgResStock_test.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: AgResStock_test.tif
Size is 722, 360
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-0.500000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.500000000000000,-0.500000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GrADS version 2.2.1.oga.1
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0.015235457
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0.023611112
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.5000000,  90.0000000) (  0d30' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (  -0.5000000, -90.0000000) (  0d30' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right (     360.500,      90.000) (360d30' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (     360.500,     -90.000) (360d30' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      ( 180.0000000,   0.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=722x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I want to match a tiff file with google map.
What are the options?